# Copying contents from one NSMutableArray to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, arrays

I have two NSMutableArrays:

```
NSMutableArray* currentMessages
NSMutableArray* items
```

I am trying to copy the contents of items into currentMessages as such:

```
[self.currentMessages addObjectsFromArray:self.items];
```

When I am debugging self.items contains 30 objects. After this operation self.currentMessages contains 0 objects.

Why is the copy not working?

Comment: You have to post more code--what you have is fine.

Comment: Are you initializing currentMessages correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dollars to doughnuts `currentMessages` is nil. A message to nil just returns nil or 0, so the message to add objects would be a no-op and then asking nil for its count will return 0. You need to allocate an NSMutableArray for that property.